# How Pub / Sub get log router filter Cloud RUN log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-pubsub

This is my Architecture diagram
[Architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXMhW.png)

have an problem is in log router if choose logs to include in sink
filter like
`resource.type="cloud_run_revision"`
`resource.labels.service_name="my_service_name"`
and in my pub / sub cant get any cloud run logs , take filter out then pub / sub can get any my project logs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: mean in my gcp project use log router filter specifiy log and pass to pub/sub have problem , use resource "cloud run" flag cant get any cloudrun logs.